# Badge implementation with react and material-ui

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get a badge icon displayed when a component has notes attached to them. I have tried three ways and I get the same results which I find odd. Which one is the best way to implement this? Or is there any other way

first
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';

```
function NotesBadge({ hasNotes }) {
    
    return (
        <Badge
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',}}
            variant="dot"
            color="primary"
            invisible={hasNotes}>
        </Badge>
    );
}

export default NotesBadge;
```

second

```html
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';

function NotesBadge({ hasNotes }) {
    
    return (
        <Badge
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',}}
            variant="dot"
            color="primary"
            invisible={!hasNotes}>
        </Badge>
    );
}

export default NotesBadge;
```

third

```html
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';

function NotesBadge({ hasNotes }) {
    if(hasNotes){
    return (
        <Badge
            anchorOrigin={{
                vertical: 'top',
                horizontal: 'right',}}
            variant="dot"
            color="primary"
            invisible={false}>
        </Badge>
    );
}
}
export default NotesBadge;
```

Answer (score 0):

**The second approach** is the way to go since `Badge` must be invisible when `hasNotes` is false, hence the name.